# state of jquery UI elements in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

How can I store the state of draggables and droppables from jquery UI into JSON? I want to save the state and retrieve them back using JSON. Is this the best way or alternate ways are also possible?

Comment: No, I am a newbie and trying to know how to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callbackhandlers of the draggable/Droppable events to get the values which have changed.

You could save those values using localStorage/sessionStorage, so you don't need to save the data to the server.

There is also an polyfill for the Storage API you can use for IE.

Try something like this:

```
$( ".yourdraggable_element" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
       localStorage.setItem("left",ui.position().left);
       localStorage.setItem("top",ui.position().top);
   }
});
```

you now can retrieve the position:

```
   $(".yourdraggable_element").css("left",localStorage.getItem("left"));
   $(".yourdraggable_element").css("top",localStorage.getItem("top"));
```

Note: this is only a starting point! E.g. you first have to check if localStorage, so please dont take this as complete solution!

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how it is implemented so that I can see and follow? I don't know where to start for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jQuery UI - http://jqueryui.com/, which supports drag-and-drop through the Draggable and Droppable interactions.  They have extensive documentation when it comes to JSON callbacks etc.